# Are Twitter replies from protected accounts visible to those not following?

Tags: twitter

I have a protected Twitter account. If I reply to a tweet from somebody I'm following, and they're not following me, will they see the reply?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They will not - taken from the **What are @Replies** section from the [Twitter FAQ](http://support.twitter.com/entries/13920-frequently-asked-questions)

> Please note that if your account is private, users who are not following you will not see your @replies or mentions.

Comment: +1 for not only providing a link but copying the relevant content. This ensures your answer is still useful in the event of link rot.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, they can. They cannot view your protected tweets directly on twitter, but they can view your tweets through topsy.com

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: that site doesn't exist